# PROLOG : Given a number X, find all multiples of 4 less or equal than X

Tags: prolog

I have the following program:

```
list4(N, L) :-
  list4(0, N, L).

list4(N, N, [N]).
list4(N0, N, [N0| List]) :-
  N0 < N,
  N1 is N0+1,
  list4(N1, N, List).
```

When i change the line `N1 is N0+1` to `N1 is 4*N0` i get `stack limit exceeded error`.

My expected result is

```
list4(10,L).
L = [4,8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems with the `4*N0` version:

1. In `list4/2` you initialize `list4/3` with N0=0, which, multiplied with anything, always stays 0. That causes the infinite recursion. As you want multiples of four, you can just keep increasing `N0` by one in each step and multiply it by 4 before putting it into the list.
2. The anchor relies on your count variable arriving at N exactly, but N0 * 4 overshoots. The first rule of `list4/3` has to cover the rest of the cases with `N0*4 > N` as well. To also include the upper limit in the result, we can make the anchor stop at values *larger* than the limit and handle the upper bound itself in the second rule.

Expressed in code:

```
list4(N, L) :-
  list4(1, N, L).

list4(N0, N, []) :- N4Times is N0*4,N4Times > N.
list4(N0, N, [N4Times| List]) :-  
  N4Times is N0*4,
  N4Times =< N,
  N1 is N0 + 1,
  list4(N1, N, List).
```

Results in:

```
?- list4(10,L).
L = [4, 8] ;
false.
?- list4(8,L).
L = [4, 8] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the accumulator with 0 and increment it by 4 at each step.

```
% list4(+Upperbound, -MultiplesOfFour)

list4(U, M) :- 
    list4(0, U, M).

list4(A, U, L) :-
    M is A+4,
    (   M =< U
    ->  L = [M|Ms],
        list4(M, U, Ms)
    ;   L = [] ).
```

Examples:

```
?- list4(10, L).
L = [4, 8].

?- list4(8, L).
L = [4, 8].

?- list4(20, L).
L = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20].

?- list4(30, L).
L = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28].

?- list4(3, L).
L = [].
```